# Correctly Deploy maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with maven, this a multimodule project

```
Mainproject
    project1 - jar
    project2 - jar
    project3 - web
```

Now that I finished the project I want to test it on the server but don't know how to upload them, on my computer I have added a plug for tomcat which deploys the war file to tomcat automatically, but the server doesn't have maven.

What is the way for moving to production with this kind of projects?

Should I just upload the target directories for each module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a few questions here.  There is the "how do I test on a server" one, and there is "what is the way for moving to production" one.  And they can be quite different.

I have assumed that the JAR files in the project are used by the WAR file and packaged within its WEB-INF/lib directory.  If I'm wrong, that's cool.  Just this sort of information is handy to know.

Maven is a build tool.  It is not a deployment tool.  What you have at the end of this, is a WAR file.  If you run mvn install (or mvn deploy) you have a SNAPSHOT version of the WAR file.  This would be suitable for quick, ad-hoc testing to other machines.  But you would most likely use methods approriate for the hosting container for making them available.  Note: a Maven DEPLOY is a different thing from a DEPLOY a war file to tomcat.

To my mind, if you're putting anything into production, or in front of a customer, or in front of a testing group, you should use Maven to make a Release of the product.  That is, using the release plugin (via the release:prepare and release:plugin goals) to create a non-SNAPSHOT release of your artifact (in this case, a official version of the WAR file).  Once you have that WAR file, you can migrate it to your production server in whatever way is easiest (copy, deploy into tomcat in the best way).  You haven't mentioned if there are database requirements for this web application, and that would need to be considered before you change any production application.

But, once you have official versions, you have tags of source code, and you can accurately know what code is being run.

What I don't think you're going to get is being able to automatically copy the WAR file into a production server from your development environment.  Here be dragons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Edh , some of this modules run as a separate jar and one of them is a war file. These projects have dependencies of other jars like hibernate, but when I see the target directory I don't see the jars and I try executing the jar directly in the target directory but it won't run because of the dependencies. How can I upload my program to the client server and be sure it's going to run? I'm new to maven

Comment: You can use Maven to build a tar or zip file which contains everything you'll need in order to deploy into a production environment.  WARs are pretty easy, in that they typically pack their own luggage.  So grabbing the war is all you need.

Comment: JAR files will need to have their dependencies as well.  Maven can provide that.  I would use the assembly plugin to package up your artifacts and those your artifacts need.  Then you can take that single file into your target environment, unpack and move as you see fit.  I've had tar files which contain the artifacts, as well as scripts which made it easier to deploy, etc, once it was in the production environment.  But those were all custom scripts, tailor made for the target environment.  Maven is not going to provide anything out of the box

Comment: Cool.  The assembly plugin can be a bit overwhelming, due to the amount of stuff it can do.  In your case with the JARS and their dependencies, you want to look at the dependencySet declaration within the assembly script (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) and use the transativeDependencies logic.  This will drag in what it needs.  This is your starting point.  If you have time, have a sanity check and ensure you're only grabbing what you use (and exclude the jars you don't).